# Laplace transform of two different Heavisides multiplied

Tags: laplace-transform

The actual problem first asks me to find the laplace transform of 
$$f(t)=u(t-1)+u(t-2)+u(t-3)$$
 which is readily obtainable by looking at a transform table to be $$F(s)=\frac{e^{-s}}{s}+\frac{e^{-2s}}{s}+\frac{e^{-3s}}{s}$$, however the problem then asks me to evaluate $$\mathcal{L}\{f(t)^2\}$$, which I am having a hard time doing. I think the minimal problem here is how to find the transform of $u(t-a)u(t-b)$. I think I should do something like  $u(t-a)u((t-a)+(a-b))$ but I am both not sure of, and even if I am right, I don't know how to follow from this step.

Comment: Can you prove that $u(t - a)u(t - b) = u(t - \max\{a,b\})$ for the unit-step function $u$?

Comment: Is $u$ the Heaviside function, usually denoted by $H$? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: Yes, $u$ is the Heaviside function, that is the notation we use in my class, don't know why.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, I can. That seems obvious now, thank you.

Comment: @bof, should $c=\max(a,b)$? Instead of $t$?

Comment: @Tucker Yes, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $$u(t-a)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1, \space t>a\\
                  0, \space t<a
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $$
And that $$u(t-b)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1, \space t>b\\
                  0, \space t<b
                \end{array}
              \right.
  $$
We realise that if $ b > a $, then, when multiplying both functions, every number before the value of $b$ is multiplied by $0$, or:
$$u(t-b)u(t-a)=\left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  1, \space t>b\\
                  0, \space t<b
                \end{array}
              \right. \space =u(t-b)
  $$

which leads us to the conclusion that $$u(t-b)u(t-a)=u(t-max\{a,b\})$$